# Android Force Close on ProgressDialog

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, rss

I am attempting to show an indeterminate ProgressDialog while grabbing an RSS feed.  I get the dialog to pop, but as soon as the results are returned, I get a force close.  My suspicion is that the adapter is populated and goes to update the UI.  The code is below.  Is my suspicion correct?

```
        public void getRSS(String rss)
    {

        new GetRSS().execute(rss);

    }
    private class GetRSS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(View2.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            Dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void nothing)
        {
            Dialog.dismiss();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... rss) {
        URL feedUrl;
        try
            {
                feedUrl = new URL(rss[0]);

                SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
                SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(feedUrl));
                List entries = feed.getEntries();

                Iterator iterator = entries.listIterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        SyndEntry ent = (SyndEntry) iterator.next();
                        String title = ent.getTitle();
                        //String uri = ent.getUri();
                        //d.add(uri);

                        SyndContent content = (SyndContent)ent.getContents().get(0);
                        d.add(content.getValue());
                        adapter.add(title);
                    }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (FeedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
        }
    }
    */
```

Here's the stack dump -- clearly the call to notify is the issue.  Now I'm just having trouble figuring out where to call notify:

```
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571): Activity com.digthisband.dtb.jg.View2 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e6ae88 that was originally added here
```

01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.digthisband.dtb.jg.View2 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e6ae88 that was originally added here
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.view.ViewRoot.(ViewRoot.java:247)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at com.digthisband.dtb.jg.View2$GetRSS.onPreExecute(View2.java:97)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at com.digthisband.dtb.jg.View2.getRSS(View2.java:87)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at com.digthisband.dtb.jg.View2.onCreate(View2.java:68)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-22 12:02:28.701: ERROR/WindowManager(571):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best if you could show the error LogCat, it will say what caused the Exception.
I also noticed you were calling notifyDataSetChanged() in the doInBackground method- you should call this only in the UI thread.

Comment: You are absolutely correct -- I've removed the call to notifyDataSetChanged and the crash is gone.  I also don't get my data.  But it's a start...

Comment: Heh... well, yes. The standard thing to do is call publishProgress() instead. This in turn will call onProgressUpdate() automatically in the UI thread, which is where you can call notifyDataSetChanged(). You will need to override onProgressUpdate().